# How can i execute the sql query with parameter?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, scalikejdbc

```
val resultList: List[List[String]] =
  sql"""
       select * from exchange_transaction
     """
    .map(
      rs =>
        List(
          rs.string("transaction_id")
        )
    )
    .list()
    .apply()
```

execute the above code,it is ok
but this sql "select * from exchange_transaction" is not fixed.
I want this sql like a parameter ,like the follow(shorthand code.....)

```
def findMemberList(segmentExecuteSql: String
    val resultList: List[List[String]] =
      sql"""
           ＄segmentExecuteSql
         """
        .map(
          rs =>
            List(
              rs.string("transaction_id")
            )
        )
        .list()
        .apply()
```

but it's error after the execution
the message is

```
[error] s.StatementExecutor$$anon$1 - SQL execution failed (Reason: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''select * from  exchange_transaction'' at line 1
Query is : 
           'select * from  exchange_transaction'
         ):

   'select * from  exchange_transaction'
```

what should i do ,how to fix the exception?

Comment: please click ->http://blog.csdn.net/djqtdj/article/details/53505561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try turning `resultList` into a function:

```scala
import scalikejdbc.SQL

def resultList(sqlQuery: String): List[List[String]] =
  SQL(sqlQuery)
    .map(
      rs =>
        List(
          rs.string("transaction_id")
        )
    )
    .list()
    .apply()
```

Comment: DBIO[_] not found

Comment: is there any else method？

Comment: What database library are you using? I assumed that it's from Slick. Also this question doesn't have anything to do with play framework so please update the tags.

Comment: mysql------------------------------

Comment: That is database which you are using and it's irrelevant for your question. The library that you use might be Slick, Anorm, scalikejdbc etc.

Comment: but I can't update ...  I am not a leader and can not make a decision

Comment: please click ->blog.csdn.net/djqtdj/article/details/53505561

Comment: Maybe just try replacing `sql"""＄segmentExecuteSql"""` with `SQL(segmentExecuteSql)`.

Comment: ................ You Don;t Know What I want,Please replace the ＄ to dollar symbol

Comment: so...I want execute a query with parameter.but It parsing( analysis) in a wrong way

Comment: try to execute it

Comment: I don't have access to your database, so I don't think it will work. Do you mean that you want to embed SQL statements inside sql-interpolated strings?

Comment: You can do it with `SQL` like this: `SQL(s"$segmentExecuteSql")`. I'm not sure if scalikejdbc allows embedding SQL statements in interpolated strings.

Comment: do u have skype ? can u guide me ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really a scalikejdbc expert. I suggest you ask on scalikejdbc gitter channel: https://gitter.im/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc

Comment: Just explain your problem and someone will eventually help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
val resultList: List[List[String]] =
  SQL(segmentExecuteSql)
    .map(
      rs =>
        List(
          rs.string("transaction_id")
        )
    )
    .list()
    .apply()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thank you for your comment, my account has been ban.do you know how to get out of a question ban?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th